# How to actually change/set environment variables from within emacs

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, environment-variables

In my shell I did: `export BLA=foo` and then I do `echo $BLA` and I see `foo` as expected. I then load up emacs and do `M-!` for a shell command and do `echo $BLA` and it's set to something else, `bar`. So then I run `M-x setenv` and give it `BLA` and `foo` at the prompts but when i do the echo i still see `bar`. Why would that be and how can I change it? I am trying to do this for some environment variables under which I want to run `M-x compile`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`setenv` will modify the environment for the processes emacs launch **after** you set the value.  Running child processes will not be affected.

Thus, doing a `(setenv "FOO" "bar")` and then `M-x shell` (provides you have not a running shell yet) will produce a shell with environment variable "FOO" set to "bar".

Comment: `C-u M-x shell` will prompt for buffer name, which has the effect of easily launching a 2nd, 3rd, etc. shell window.  Try shell before and after a setenv and see the results!

Comment: It's worth adding that this will modify env for the Emacs process itself, so if you wanted new variable to be limited to child processes but not to Emacs itself, this isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Your shell in which you've started the Emacs hands over a copy of its environment to its child process (the Emacs), that's how the value is transmitted from the shell to the Emacs.  Any change the Emacs then performs with its inherited environment will only affect the Emacs process's environment.  There is no way the Emacs's environment can influence the environment of the shell.

If you need to hand information back to the shell, you have to use different techniques like temp files, named pipes, sockets, …

If you just want to check the environment of the Emacs itself, use `M-x` `getenv` to look at variables, or use `M-!` `echo $BLA`.  If this also is showing sth else, then you probably have a special `BLA` which is automatically set to sth after each command, or which isn't writable at all like `RANDOM` or similar.

Comment: I really like how you refer to Emacs at _The Emacs_. I'm gonna adopt this convention

Comment: The Emacs has been described as a bizarr monster, so the term »Emacs« should be considered more a specification than a name, hence »The Emacs«.